# Retrieve only one table row from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a list of table rows stored in a variable, is there a way of placing only one of those rows (with a specific ID) in to anoter variable?

For example, if `tableRows` was this -

```
<tr id="0"></tr>
<tr id="1"></tr>
<tr id="2"></tr>
<tr id="3"></tr>
<tr id="4"></tr>
```

How could I set `singleRow` to `<tr id="2"></tr>`?

Comment: Is `tableRows` a HTML string or a jQuery object? Have you had a look at the documentation, e.g. [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)?

Comment: Do you mean that `tableRows` is a jquery object containing those rows or that it is a string with that text?  Also, your `id`s should not start with a number, except I believe in HTML5.

Comment: Sorry, it's an HTML string. And my ID's are not actually numbers, that is just a (poor) example! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `tableRows` contains a string of HTML:

```
var singleRow = $(tableRows).filter("#2");
```

If it's already a jQuery object wrapping the HTML string then you can omit the call to jQuery:

```
var singleRow = tableRows.filter("#2");
```

The [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method reduces the matched set of elements to those matching the selector (or passing a test defined by a function).

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gMBwy/3/).

However, it may be worth noting that the resulting `singleRow` variable will contain an instance of jQuery, not a string literal like `tableRows` contains. To extract a string out of that you need a little bit of trickery:

```
var str = $("<div>").append($(rows).filter("#2")).html();
```

Basically, you append the desired element to a new one (in this case it's a `div`) and then call `html` on that. As the `html` method returns a string, you have a string containing the contents of the new element, which is your desired element.

Comment: Hmm, seems I got a bit ahead of myself. Using your code (original string was an HTML), the single row seems to be captured, but it is as an object. All I need is that portion of the HTML from the original string. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard - Yeah, I noted that in my original answer. I've updated the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks James, I'll give that a bash.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
 $("#2")
```

to get `<tr id="2"></tr>`

[EDIT] As pointed out by Felix Kling in his comment, if your variable `tableRows` was a jquery object **and** you didn't want to filter by **id** but by another kind of selector (not a unique one), you should consider using `.filter()` as James Allardice showed in his answer.
[EDIT 2] (Credits to James Montagne in the comments) this is also true if your tables rows don't exist yet and are still an object variable

Remember that selecting by `id` is the fastest (and easiest) way to select, provided that your HTML is correct and your id is unique.

Comment: The EDIT is also true if the rows don't actually exist on the DOM but were simply created in memory.  `$("<tr...")`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using id's then

```
$('#2')
```

Answer (score 1):

with id you can do this-

```
$('#2')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest staying specifying the type of tag you are expecting. So like dknaack suggested or

`$('tr#2')`

would be more specific. But everyone here is correct. It's the basics of Jquery seletors. Which also happen to be the same as CSS selectors. You can also find more on selectors from the JQuery docs. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
var tableRows = $('tr'),
    singleRow = tableRows[2];
```

Comment: This would work in the case of the example code in the question, but the OP wants a way to get a specific row by `id`, not index.

Comment: ah I see, then I'd go with your suggestion of the .filter()